# too long time to load controls on Windows phone

Tags: wpf, windows, windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1

I have a page which contains two grids(basic textbox etc) and background image(under 500k), and a third party chart.
Every time when the page is new created/initialized, I found out it takes about 2,3 sec to load. 
After I disable the chart, it will be around 1 sec faster. How can I make it more fluent?

Using Lumia 930

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[These](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh994641.aspx) are some ways to optimize XAML.

However, in some cases, beyond optimization, some controls take time and you can display a progress bar in the meantime.

One point to note is that you should never execute CPU intensive operations on UI thread using `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke();`. That would slow down your XAML loading. Instead, create a new `Task` for CPU heavy methods, then call `Dispatcher` for UI changes alone

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Is that possible to make a splash screen within the app? Though I know this makes not good user experience.

Comment: Regarding splash screen within app, you can simply use a XAML page, then change transition behaviours accordingly, then redirect to main page, then clear `BackStack` (or else, when exiting the app, the user should go to splash again)